Power bi value conversion from thousand to million
I am trying to convert the below two value to million. But for some reason it is not showing up.
Value in excel
0.7290
5.0605
solution for the above problem. i tried many method but it doesnt now show up.i tried manual value conversion, decimal point round and other. Please help me on the same

What do you mean by converting a number to million? Like for 5 to show 0.000005M?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
